# Do assets access work from any webpage or just local asset webpages?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to add a script to an existing webpage hosted at www.example.com. So I call:

```
 webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

I am also changing the following settings:

```
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    }
```

Then on the `onPageStarted` event I try to inject some javascript this way:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:var script1 = document.createElement( 'script' );" +
                    "script1.type = 'text/javascript';script1.src =   'file:///android_asset/firstfunction.js';" +
                    " document.documentElement.appendChild(script1);");
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
E/Web Console﹕ Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/firstfunction.js at null:0
```

I have loaded these same files using my own url scheme, so I know they work just fine. I have other ways to load them as well but I wanted to try out the `file:///android_asset/` stuff. Is that not the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, remote content is not allowed to load local content.

You could achieve the same effect by loading the local JS in your app on the Java side into a String, and injecting that String directly (with the same `javascript:` URL approach).

Comment: Thanks, yeah like I said I have it working on many other ways, I was just hoping with this I might be able to insert an iframe with local content and with `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` I might be able to access other iframes but I guess not.